# What is the difference between void function and empty return type functions in Dart lang?

Tags: function, dart, difference, return-type

What is the **difference** between these two **functions** in ***Dart***?

```
void _someFunction() {
  // some logic here
}

_someOtherFunction() {
  // some other logic here
}
```

So basically my question is that is there some kind of difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a return type the return type is assumed to be `dynamic` rather than `void`. A function that returns `void` doesn't return a value. Whereas a function that returns `dynamic` could return anything, but not in a way that is particularly type safe.

For example

```dart
void _someFunction() {
  // some logic here
  return 10; // compile-time error
}

_someOtherFunction() {
  // some other logic here
  return 10; // no compile-time error
}
```